# How to create a color scheme generator for a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, color-scheme, color-picker

I am trying to make a (somewhat simple) color scheme generator for a webpage. I need it to look exactly like this image (or as close as I can get it):

[image: Color scheme generator:]

Is there any websites out or other areas I can look to find examples on how to do this? I couldn't find any code examples online.

The tags may be off, I'm not sure which language I would need to use. (Please edit if so)

Comment: That looks like a color picker to me (i.e. it's used to pick a *single* color). What exactly makes it a "color scheme generator"?

Comment: you could easily use multiple pickers to create a "color scheme generator" / "color scheme creator"

Comment: @Blowsie: of course you can. I was just unsure, because he said "I need **it** to look ...", and I thought "it" referred to the whole color scheme generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery Color Picker seems to be what your looking for.

For example.

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Comment: Ah! The demo looks exactly like what SsRide360 requested!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [kulor](http://kuler.adobe.com/): It's a flash site but it works and has lots of themes.

http://kuler.adobe.com/

Answer (score 0):

- http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic
- http://www.dematte.at/colorPicker/
- http://www.colorpicker.com/
- http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/js_color_picker_v2/js_color_picker_v2.html
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/colorpicker/
- http://safalra.com/web-design/javascript/widgets/colour-picker/
- http://www.colorjack.com/software/dhtml+color+picker.html
- http://colourmod.com/
- http://johndyer.name/lab/colorpicker/ ( http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/ for jquery)
- http://moorainbow.woolly-sheep.net/#demos
- http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/widget/tests/test_ColorPicker.html
- http://www.mozilla.org/editor/ui_specs/ColorPickerWidget.html
- http://www.visibone.com/swatches/